# SpatiaLite v4.0.0 RecoverGeometryColumn violates Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed]'

Tags: sqlite, gis, spatialite

When creating a spatial table and recovering the geometry using the RecoverGeometryColumn function if you don't specify the geometry column as lower case you end up getting a 'violates Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed]' error.

Am I doing something wrong or I have missed some documentation somewhere?

Comment: I had the same problem. My issue was that I was setting that I was expecting points as a type via AddGeometryColumn and then trying to put Polygons.

Answer (score 5):

To give an example:

1. Create a table that has a spatial column

   ```
   CREATE TABLE "test1" (
   "PK_UID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   "Geometry" MULTIPOLYGON)
   ```
2. Recover the geometry

   ```
   SELECT RecoverGeometryColumn('test1', 'Geometry', 2, 'MULTIPOLYGON',2);
   ```
3. Look at the triggers that were created

   ```
   select * from sqlite_master where type='trigger' and lower(tbl_name)='test1'
   ```

Results:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER "ggi_test1_Geometry" BEFORE INSERT ON "test1"
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ROLLBACK, 'test1.Geometry violates Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed]')
    WHERE (SELECT type FROM geometry_columns
    WHERE f_table_name = 'test1' AND f_geometry_column = 'Geometry'
    AND GeometryConstraints(NEW."Geometry", type, srid, 'XY') = 1) IS NULL;
    END

    CREATE TRIGGER "ggu_test1_Geometry" BEFORE UPDATE ON "test1"
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ROLLBACK, 'test1.Geometry violates Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed]')
    WHERE (SELECT type FROM geometry_columns
    WHERE f_table_name = 'test1' AND f_geometry_column = 'Geometry'
    AND GeometryConstraints(NEW."Geometry", type, srid, 'XY') = 1) IS NULL;
    END
```

Compare with what is in the geometry_columns table

```
    select * from geometry_columns
```

Results:

f_table_name f_geometry_column type coord_dimension srid  spaitial_index_enabled

test1        geometry          MULTIPOLYGON XY   2     0

Conclusion:
Note that the geometry_columns table the f_geometry_column is specified as 'geometry' but the trigger is looking for 'Geometry'. This causes the 'Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed]' issue. So the fix is keep you spatial column names lower case.

Comment: I've tried this but I'm still getting the same error with

"CREATE TABLE Sessions([SessionId] TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, [SessionCompletedDate] TEXT NOT NULL, [shape] POINT NULL)",
                    "SELECT RecoverGeometryColumn('Sessions', 'shape', -1, 'POINT', 2)", 
                    "SELECT CreateSpatialIndex('Sessions', 'shape')",